# creating a hierarchy using do loop

Tags: loops, sas

I'm trying to build a hierarchy from two columns where by one column is a client identifier and the other is its direct parent but I have an issue because a client can have a parent which can have another parent.

At the moment I have a number of merge statements in a macro that

```
%macro hierarchy (level);
    data sourcedata (drop = PARENT_ID);
        merge sourcedata (in = a)
              inputdata (in = b);
        by CLIENT_ID;
        if a;
        length Parent_L&level $32.;
        Parent_L&level = PARENT_ID;

        if Parent_L&level = Parent_L%eval(&level-1) then Parent_L&level ="";
        CLIENT_ID = Parent_L&level;

    proc sort; 
        by Parent_L&level;
    run;
%mend;
%hierarchy(2)
%hierarchy(3)
%hierarchy(4)
```

my output looks like

```
client_ID  Parent_L1 Parent_L2 Parent_L3 Parent_L4
clientA    clientB   .          .         .  
ClientE    clientA   clientB    .         .
```

what I'm looking for is a way to do this until the last parent_Ln is all blank as I'm not sure how many levels I need to go to

thanks

Comment: Do you have SAS/OR? If so look into PROC BOM.

Comment: This link may be helpful, there are quite a few ways to do this without doing macros. https://communities.sas.com/message/207747#207747

Comment: The thread supplied by @Reeza was really handy. A later response also shows a way that handles tree structures: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Request-for-immediate-assistance/m-p/186134#M47265. You can add `5 18 18 19 18 20` to the `cards` to see how it resolves it into subnet 1.

Answer (score 0):

The length you need is the depth of the tree. 
It is a bit cumbersome to compute that in SQL, since you really need a hash table, or at least arrays. 
You could use a [hash in data step or ds2](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ds2ref/68056/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0vfchlr4lsxmkn1wxhx59fnqj1l.htm) to access the parent from the child. 
If you have SAS/OR, then it is easier: 
you can solve a [shortest path](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/67517/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_networksolver_details26.htm) and produce your table from 
the paths from the roots of the forest. 
For this example I will use the dataset from  [the link Reeza provided](https://communities.sas.com/message/207747#207747):

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter='|';
input subject1 subject2;
datalines;
        2    |    4 
        2    |    5 
        2    |    6 
        2    |    8
        4    |    7 
        4    |    11 
        6    |    9 
        6    |    10
        6    |    12
        10  |    15 
        10  |    16 
        13  |    14 
        16  |    17
;

proc optmodel printlevel=0;
    set<num,num> REFERRALS;
    set CLIENTS = union{<u,v> in REFERRALS} {u, v};
    set ROOTS = CLIENTS diff setof{<u,v> in REFERRALS} v;
    read data have into REFERRALS=[subject1 subject2];

    /* source, sink, seq, tail, head. */
    set<num,num,num,num,num> PATHS;
    num len{ROOTS,CLIENTS} init .;
    num longest = max(of len[*]);
    solve with NETWORK / graph_direction = directed
        links     = ( include = REFERRALS )
        out       = ( sppaths = PATHS spweights = len )
        shortpath = ( source  = ROOTS  )
    ;

    num parent{ci in CLIENTS, i in 1 .. longest} init .;
    for{<u, v, i, s, t> in PATHS} 
        parent[v, len[u,v] - i + 1] = s;
    print parent;
    create data want from [client]=CLIENTS
        {i in 1 .. longest} <COL('Parent_L'||i) = parent[client,i]>;
quit;
```